# ¿Cómo usar un archivo .json como almacenamiento para mi arreglo de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, base-de-datos, javascript-objeto

Creé un arreglo de objetos tipo "Receta" con (nombre, ingredientes, procedimiento) como parámetros.. y lo guardé en el localstorage.. Pero quiero guardarlos en un archivo (ejemplo: recetas.json) para poder usarlo como base de datos.
Si podrían ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Puedes usar `fs` para guardar el contenido, y `JSON.stringify` para convertir el objeto a una cadena. Algo como `fs.writeFileSync(rutaArchivo, JSON.stringify(contentido));`. Aunque igual podrias incluir un [mcve] con lo que has intentado hasta el momento (ya que no das muchos detalles sobre tu ambiente), puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento. También te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para que veas cómo mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas.

Comment: Creo que tendras que enviar las recetas desde JS o html al servidor para que ahi se encargue de guardarlo, JavaScript no esta diseñado (sin NodeJs claro) para almacenar informacion en la base de datos(Por temas de seguridad claro), solo esta diseñado para hacer mas dinamica la pagina, pero se ha agregado una funcionalidad calidad interesante para ello:  [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) . Aunque tampoco soy experto en JS por lo que puede que me equivoque

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.